# Type argument at moment of use

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-query

I'm trying to build a generic tool for handling the response to [React Query](https://react-query.tanstack.com/typescript) `useQuery` requests in my app, and build this out using TypeScript, so that the data is correctly typed.

In a parent component, the use case would be something like this:

```
const queryResult = useQuery<MyResponseType, Error>('whatever');

return (
  <ReactQueryLoader useQueryResult={queryResult}>
    {data => {
      // Data should be of MyResponseType type, but is unknown
      return <pre>{JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}</pre>;
    }}
  </ReactQueryLoader>
);
```

I tried defining this ReactQueryLoader as so:

```
import React from "react";
import { UseQueryResult } from "react-query";

import { Loading } from "./Loading";

interface ReactQueryLoaderProps {
  useQueryResult: UseQueryResult<unknown, Error>;
  handleError?: (error: Error) => void;
  children: (data: unknown) => JSX.Element;
}

export const ReactQueryLoader = ({
  useQueryResult,
  handleError = error => {
    console.error(error);
    throw new Error(error.message);
  },
  children,
}: ReactQueryLoaderProps): null | JSX.Element => {
  if (useQueryResult.isError) {
    handleError(useQueryResult.error);
    return null;
  }

  if (useQueryResult.isLoading) {
    return <Loading />;
  }

  return children(useQueryResult.data);
};
```

But when I inspect the `data` passed to the child, instead of being the type of the expected response data, it is unknown. I'm having trouble getting this to work, as someone with a mid-low-level understanding of TypeScript. I thought I could apply the same pattern as in [this answer to another question I had](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72222422/dynamically-define-argument-type/72222471#72222471), but I can't figure out how to do it in this context.

I tried this:

```
interface ReactQueryLoaderProps {
  // ...
  children: <T extends unknown>(data: T) => JSX.Element;
}
```

But got this in the parent element:

```
(parameter) data: T extends unknown
```

I also tried:

```
interface ReactQueryLoaderProps {
  useQueryResult:  UseQueryResult<T extends unknown, Error>;
```

But that provoked two errors:

- Under the T: `Cannot find name 'T'.`
- Under the comma: `'?' expected.`

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ReactQueryLoader` function needs to be generic here, as well as the props type.

That might look something like this:

```
interface ReactQueryLoaderProps<T extends UseQueryResult<unknown, Error>> {
  useQueryResult: T;
  handleError?: (error: Error) => void;
  children: (data: T['data']) => JSX.Element;
}
```

And

```
export function ReactQueryLoader<T extends UseQueryResult<unknown, Error>>({
  useQueryResult,
  handleError,
  children,
}: ReactQueryLoaderProps<T>): null | JSX.Element {
  //...
}
```

Here `ReactQueryLoader` is now a generic function that captures the query result type as `T` and passes that to the generic props type `ReactQueryLoaderProps`.

`ReactQueryLoaderProps` then uses that type as the type of `useQueryResult`, and pulls the `['data']` property from that type for the type of the `children` function parameter.

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?module=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4BYAKFEljgG84BXAZyQEUmkoBPAGjgBVNp249kLJgBt4AXzjZcBIuhgBaAI5deZKlQAmSNFJREFTAHYZgEC3AAyEFPuAWA5gAoAlAC44AKQBlAA0AOgBRKSQQJAsYPWo47kx0JERiGFFeR2duAAUcMBYAHgAVOCQADxhY-RYhEW1xJEkZYssAawsIAHcLAXCoHCgAPhGGKjhmRrEJaRg-UopKKYALFAt9KMHhgH4-D25hvx3oLzgAXnGANwhgfWWptFXgKX0iCwP9FBgURYBtADk31+gIAuucrgEQhEojE4stZAkqrQsJZrLZ0qosjwcoYoGUKtVavVhBwmnM2p1un0BkNoGMPPRJtNybMWvM+Cz1pttvSoJcKvzLuNmSspnA0LYWBAoqEjtBDvyvI8JTBVjgenALEgtacoErhqEYiwWCg3EgVSzZFzxc9Xu9YrbZH5kNimnj8oUSqURr5tdIpHAAD7QsKRaKxeBiqbATBwDysNm8SkwULAFj684xiU8rZIfWJmYpjkyeXK1VTIgwJhQOwWQOqpGUFlxhNJnGp9MsPGuNzZllVpA1utwYq99xwAD0IybCSHI7s9reHyLyearTTIJQVsosmWVFcNSgKTQaQAshvIBY2KUeGA0owQFfpUg7w+-AAjCCy1B2ZtUFKN7wFo7KboKHZNMUl4SNet73kgdLDCMHiAj06w1Nc3CAruQEsFgP6CsUboYDinoCpBYHzBc9CgSWm6yCMLL0NuIoTOKC61nYxRgEQIz0EEADyAByoT4VAfZxjwHjbgIDZSFIAgAExeLIxRTrxSCztOU5wKxGZwBA8YwAhcAwS0cFvgh1rNupJGZB6Tj4iMQA)

Comment: Amazing! I'mma have to look into the term "generic" in TypeScript. Seems to be what I often want. Thanks!

Comment: The handbook is a great entry point on this: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html